# cursor.fetchall() in MySQL Python module

Tags: python, sql, ubuntu

I want to practice my skill in using MySQL querys in python scripts.
At first I'm working at script which will be able to get all databases from my `sql` server( I'm using ubuntu).

I've written this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys

try:
    con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'testuser', 'test')

    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES;")

    for row in cursor:
    print row

except mdb.Error, e:
    print "Errot %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if con:
    con.close()
```

And it returns:

```
('information_schema',)
('test',)

While I have more that that 2 databases - Output from mysql console is:
mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+

| Database           |

+--------------------+

| information_schema |

| mysql              |

| performance_schema |

| test               |

| test1              |

+--------------------+
```

Can you get me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the same user from your console as from your Python script? (i.e. username: testuser password: testuser)

Comment: Thanks :D 
It was so stupid mistake, now it works fine :)